# Linq to entities many to many left join tree

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm unsing EF6 Code First and I have 5 tables/entities with many-to-many relations like so:

```
[Table("TableA")]
public class TableA {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string PropA { get; set; }
}

[Table("TableB")]
public class TableB {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string PropB { get; set; }
}

[Table("TableC")]
public class TableC {
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string PropC { get; set; }
}

[Table("TableAB")]
public class TableAB {
  [ForeignKey("TableA")]
  public Guid TableAId { get; set; }
  public TableA { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("TableB")]
  public Guid TableBId { get; set; }
  public TableB { get; set; }
}

[Table("TableBC")]
public class TableBC {
  [ForeignKey("TableB")]
  public Guid TableBId { get; set; }
  public TableB { get; set; }
  [ForeignKey("TableC")]
  public Guid TableCId { get; set; }
  public TableC { get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking to use linq to entities and obtain a "tree" object as follow, without using navigation:

```
new List<A_DTO>() {
  Id: ...
  PropA: ...
  B: new List<B_DTO>(){
    Id: ...
    PropB: ...
    C: new List<C_DTO>(){
       Id: ...
       PropC: ...
    }
  }
}
```

Another problem that I have is that in some situations no records will exist between A and B or B and C, that's why I'm using left join.
What I've tried and it looks very messy and not sure it works as expected:

```
from a in Repository.All<TableA>()
join abT in Repository.All<TableAB>() on a.Id equals abT.TableAId into abTemp
from ab in abTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
join bT in Repository.All<TableB>() on ab.TableBId equals bT.Id into bTemp
from b in bTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
join abT in Repository.All<TableBC>() on b.Id equals bcT.TableBId into bcTemp
from bc in bcTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
join cT in Repository.All<TableC>() on bc.TableCId equals cT.Id into cTemp
from c in bTemp.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new A_DTO(){
   Id: a.Id,
   PropA: a.PropA,
   B: abTemp.Select(_ab => new B_DTO(){
      Id: _ab.B.Id, // what if _ab.B is null?
      PropB: _ab.B.PropB,
      C: bcTemp.Select(_bc => new C_DTO(){
         Id: _bc.C.Id, // what if _bc.C is null?
         PropC: _bc.C.PropC
      }
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do this in a more easy/pleasant way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work (This tells EF not to use lazy loading for B and B.C therefore including the objects):

```
Repository.All()<TableA>().Include(x => x.B).Include(x => x.B.C)
```

By default all related objects are virtual properties and treated as lazy load. You will not need to do this for properties on the object so a.propa and a.b.propa will be included just by including the B property.